# Angular 2 vendor.css looking in wrong spot for material design icons

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

Recently, i've updated to angular material for my project; I've added material design icons via webpack.config with the following code.

```
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    'mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css',
    'mdi/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.eot',
    'mdi/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf',
    'mdi/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.woff',
    'mdi/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.woff2',
]
```

When starting the project; i get GET errors that they cannot be found. The request url is http://localhost:55672/dist/dist/ and the caller is vendor.css?
dist/dist is clearly incorrect and i'm unsure as to where to configure its location to look. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should probably use relative paths istead

Comment: Are you using the Angular-CLI? Why not just import these using a sass-loader?

Comment: I am not; I wanted to minimize dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by changing the public path in webpack.config.vendor.js from "dist/" to "". Unsure of the direct cause of this issue but I suppose it will work.

in